# Can't launch WinForms program after moving .exe

Tags: c#, winforms

As in title. It works in Visual Studio, it works when .exe is in Debug, but it won't launch when i move it. Most obvious problem would be using resources in specific location, but everything is in the program and there are no paths used. Any other ideas?

Edit

Downloaded backup of last working version. Found the issue - it appears after downloading CSVHelper from NuGet. I definitely need it. How to make it work?

Comment: Did you move it to another computer, or just another folder on that computer?

Also, if it was compiled in debug mode, you need the debug symbols file in order to run the code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the same PC, just clicked Build Solution. I have backup of working version, i will try to check what can be the issue.

Comment: Start by cleaning the solution to remove any previous libraries. Then I would check for any possible unhandled exceptions in the startup methods or dependencies constructors.

Comment: @AndyStagg tried cleaning, no changes.

Comment: You can also delete the bin and obj folders, or at least making sure the folders are empty after a clean. Empty the recycle bin... beyond that, you're going to have to retrace your steps. It could be as simple as commenting out lines via trial and error, setting up some form of simple logging.

Comment: @AndyStagg but isn't it weird that adding one package ruins whole project? Or maybe its actually dependant on something? Maybe i just don't know how to build it properly.

Comment: Check the build dependencies for the nuget package, and their compatibility with your project. IE, .Net Framework, .Net Standard, .Net Core... It's not strange for an external dependency to cause fatal errors within your project...

Comment: @Joel: "if it was compiled in debug mode, you need the debug symbols file in order to run the code" is not correct and I'm quite surprised with your experience that you would think that.  You do very often need debug versions of libraries that you used, if you linked with the debug version.  But debug symbols are non-essential, they help a lot with attaching a debugger and make stack traces quite a lot more informative, but life goes on just fine without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to run the program on another computer, you might need to publish it to get all of the dependencies (Toolbar->Build->Publish), or add a setup project; you will have to install that project type.  MS No longer includes it (not sure why).  Here is the link for the setup project: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects . With the setup project you will have to configure it, but it will package all of your program libraries and create an MSI installer.  You see these all the time when installing software that you download.

Comment: I have been told that .exe contains everything (which is honestly kind of strange, especially if you decide to create something bigger than one project). And yes i have been tricked. Moving whole Release folder fixes the issue. But i will mark your reply as solution, and read something about it.